# Replacing string if it contains specified pattern

Tags: python, regex

I need to replace `ravi.jhon@piramal.com|` or sam`.jennifer@piramal.com|` to

`''`(empty strings).I have written following regex but its unable to deal

with `.` `-` `emptyspace` in the strings.

my regex  is  `\w+@ongoose.com["|"]`

now question is how to include `.`, `empty space`,`-` along with alpha numeric characters

my final output  should be : `ravi.jhon@piramal.com|` to ``

Comment: Try `r'\S+\|(?!\S)'`. What do you mean by `emptyspace`?

Comment: empty space means zero length string

Comment: Well, if you plan to just match word chars, `.` and `-` in the user name part, you may use `r'[\w.-]+@ongoose\.com\|'`. BTW, `["|"]` matches `"` or `|`

Comment: Thanks! it worked @Wiktor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the character you want to match in a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[\w.-].`

In you example you want to match `piramal` and in your regex you want to match `ongoose`. To match both of them you might use an alternation `(?:ongoose|piramal)` or match any non whitespace character using `\S+` and replace with an empty string.

To match [a dot](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) you have to escape it `\.`

[`[\w.-]+@\S+\.com\|`](https://regex101.com/r/rccoCE/1)